# Date and time conversion in C# - DateTime.ParseExact() not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have date/time format, for example:
 "1-Mar-13 92230"
According to [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and [this link](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) the format is as follows:
"d-MMM-yy Hmmss", because:

```
Day is single digit, 1-30
Month is 3 letter abbreviation, Jan/Mar etc.
Year is 2 digits, eg 12/13
Hour is single digit for 24 hour clock, eg 9, 13 etc. (no 09)
Minute is standard (eg 01, 52)
Second is standard (eg 30, 02)
```

I'm trying to run the following code in my program, but I keep getting an error of "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
string input = "1-Mar-13 92330";
        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "d-MMM-yy Hmmss", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Please help, I'm not too familiar with DateTime conversions, but I can't see where I've gone wrong here. Thanks!

UPDATE: Is this because time cannot be parsed without colons in between? (eg 1-Mar-13 9:22:30 gets parsed, but i have an external data source that would be impossible to rewrite from Hmmss to H:mm:ss)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could fix your date:

```
var parts = "1-Mar-13 92230".Split(' ');

if (parts[1].Length == 5)
{
    parts[1] = "0" + parts[1];
}

var newDate = parts[0] + " " + parts[1];

var date = DateTime.ParseExact(newDate, "d-MMM-yy HHmmss",  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: This works for me. Tested with the date/time in the question, and "1-Mar-13 102230". Works for all cases. Most importantly, it's convenient as far as not modifying the source data goes (eg adding spaces, etc.). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

> If format is a custom format pattern that does not include date or
>   time separators (such as "yyyyMMdd HHmm"), use the invariant culture
>   for the provider parameter and the widest form of each custom format
>   specifier. For example, if you want to specify hours in the format
>   pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form,
>   "H".

so you can try:

```
string input = "1-Mar-13 92330";
        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "d-MMM-yy Hmmss", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: this is still giving the exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

Comment: I second Rex's comment. For whatever reason, i still get the exception

Answer (score 1):

Your input string has to be of following format

```
string input = "1-Mar-13 092330";
```

If you go back to your link, it says

```
H   24-hour clock hour (e.g. 19)
```

Now H is 24 hours, it should be represented with leading 0. If not imagine how would you handle the case of hours greater than 9 i.e which are in double digit.

If not your hour and Minute and Seconds has to be separated.

```
string input = "1-Mar-13 9 2330";

var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "d-MMM-yy H mmss", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hour min and seconds need to be separated, as they are not getting distinguished.

```
string input = "1-Mar-13 9 23 30";
        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "d-MMM-yy H mm ss",   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```